# (GStreamer) Can't get rtmpsink to open properly?

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I've been learning GStreamer to manage and forward streams from one RTMP server to another. I've hit a roadblock when trying to replicate the tutorial found [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/streaming.html?gi-language=c), albeit without the data buffer. Whenever I run the program, it stops when I set the `rtmpsink` URL. It doesn't throw an error on that line or report that the pipeline couldn't start to `ret`, it just stops. The first part of the code is below

```
    GstElement* pipeline = nullptr;
    GstBus* bus = nullptr;
    GstMessage* msg = nullptr;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    gboolean terminate = FALSE;
    GstElement* source, *sink, *mux;

    gst_init(&arg, &argv);


    // Create Elements
    source = gst_element_factory_make("rtmpsrc","source");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make("rtmpsink","sink");
    mux = gst_element_factory_make("flvmux", "mux");

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");

    // add items to bin and 
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, mux, sink, NULL);
    if (!gst_element_link_many(source, mux, sink, NULL)) {
        g_printerr("oh no");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    g_object_set(source, "location", "rtmp://localhost/live/Stream-A");

    // Here is where the code stops
    g_object_set(sink, "location", "rtmp://localhost/live/Stream-B");

    ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }
```

I've looked for other questions about `rtmpsink`, most of the answers said to use `flvmux` to format the audio and video properly.

Is there something I'm missing in the `set` call? Should I use a different sink?

**Update 1**
After a bit more digging, I've realized that I was debugging the wrong way. After using VS correctly, I ran into the following error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9FC2B1C3C (vcruntime140.dll)
in gstream_switch.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 
0x0000000000000000
```

So it looks like this is just a case of referencing unallocated memory. I haven't found the answer, so I'm not marking this answered yet. Looking at other posts, my guess is that maybe I'm not using debugging libraries/variables, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g_object_set()` needs to end with a `NULL` parameter to indicate an end as you can set multiple parameters with one call.

Try:

```
g_object_set(source, "location", "rtmp://localhost/live/Stream-A", NULL);
g_object_set(sink, "location", "rtmp://localhost/live/Stream-B", NULL);
```